# Ruby JSON.parse error

Tags: ruby, regex, json

I am building a script that uses a cURL command against an API.  I send the cURL command formatted as an `application/json` request and get the result, which I parse into a Ruby hash.

This works great when I use cURL POST commands, getting the correctly formatted JSON responses. However, when using cURL GET commands I am returned a JSON document that has headers:

```
puts r:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Compute-Request-Id: req-7e625990-068b-47d1-8c42-9d3dd3b27050
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 1209
Date: Wed, 16 Jan 2013 20:47:41 GMT

{ <JSON DATA> }
```

When I try and do a `JSON.parse(r)` I get an unexpected token error at 'HTTP/1.1.'.

My method for this:

```
def list_flavors

    r = %x(curl -s -k -D - -H \"X-Auth-Token: #{$token}\" -X 'GET' http://10.30.1.49:8774/v2/27e60c130c7748f48b0e3e9175702c30/flavors -H 'Content-type:     application/json')

   response = JSON.parse(r)

   response
end
```

Is there a way to use regular expressions to pull the body out of the JSON doc and then parse?

Or am I going about this the wrong way when getting the response from cURL?

Comment: If you don't want the headers, why are you passing the -D - option? Using net/http as suggested would be better anyway (or perhaps one of the wrappers such as restclient)

Comment: Hey Frederick - Thanks for this!

Comment: Why don't you use the [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) gem? It makes dealing with cURL a bit easier and idiomatic.

Comment: Ill have to take a look, still new to the Ruby world :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to find a way to cut out that header before passing the string into `JSON.parse`.  `JSON.parse` expects valid json only.

Rather than curling and using the thing wholesale as a string, I'd suggest you use the very versatile ruby [Net::HTTP](http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/HTTP) and/or [OpenURI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) libraries, which will allow you to easily access just your response's body without the header.

Comment: I had checked out URI before, but the API I am making the requests against was strict about using cURL POST, GET and DELETE commands to retrieve the JSON or send the JSON responses.

Comment: The lower-level Net::HTTP can use any request header, ie. `Net::HTTP::Get.new`, `Net::HTTP::Post.new`, and `Net::HTTP::Delete.new`. They are effectively indistinguishable from curl requests to the API you are accessing.

Comment: Good to know, I will look into Net::HTTP

Comment: Great. Let me know if you have any other issues via comment, or none by flagging this as an answer.

Comment: Hey Chris, I actually figured my problem...it was a RTFM moment.  In my curl request i had a -d - command which requests a header.  I removed that and I get just the JSON body.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: Glad you figured it out! I forgot about that flag. I'd still suggest employing `Net::HTTP`, however. It's the proper tool for the job, and offers more flexibility down the line. Even if this is code you won't be returning to, it's a solid library to acquaint yourself with.

Comment: Definitely!  I actually have been going through and checking it out.  Once I get this project done I will go back through and refactor with the new libraries!